# javascript remove a string from within a string

Tags: javascript

I have the following code so far

```
var dbasedata = document.forms[0]._dbase_name.value;
        dbasedata = dbasedata.toUpperCase();
        dbasedata = dbasedata.replace(/\s/g, "");
```

The next thing I want to do is to further remove the text "UK_CONTACTS" from the already trimmed string. note; sometimes "UK_CONTACTS" may not be present in the string (note sure if that's important)

Comment: You are already using a method to remove substrings/characters in your code above.  It is very simple to extend to what you want to do..

Comment: How can't you find while you already did it with spaces?

Comment: This question shows no research effort.

Comment: Why are these comments okay... If I was making these comments I would have been banned :P

Comment: Hi, I do research all my questions beforehand but because I have only been trying to program for a week or so I get a bit lost in it all. Sorry.

Comment: Its ok user1424626! Thats why Stack Overflow is an exception in .Net and a place where you get answers to why you are getting such exceptions on the interweb! God bless dimension-ality! Just don't forget to accept the answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
dbasedata = dbasedata.replace(/UK_CONTACTS/g, "");
```

Just as you did with spaces.

Answer (score -1):

```
dbasedata = dbasedata.replace(/UK_CONTACTS/g, "");
```

Comment: `dbasedata.replace(/UK_CONTACTS/g, "")`

Because the replace method uses regular expressions this will not work on `'UK_CONTACTSUK_CONTACTS UK_CONTACTS'`

Comment: what @Jay is saying is that this will only replace the first occurrence of the string, not every occurrence.

Comment: @jbabey, Correct... nicely stated :P

Comment: Yep, should have put a bit more thought into it